# How to raise ClickEvent of Microsoft Chart Control?

Tags: c#, event-handling, onclick

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.click.aspx

The event handler:

```
protected void Chart1_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
        //stuff
}
```

I would like to raise this event manually.

```
public ActionResult HistoricalDrillDown(int reportID, string postBackValue)
{
    string sessionKey = string.Format("HistoricalReport: {0}", reportID);
    LineChart lineChart = (LineChart)Session[sessionKey];

    ImageMapEventArgs imageMapEventArgs = new ImageMapEventArgs(postBackValue);
    //Raise lineChart.Click() using ImageMapEventArgs
}
```

I feel like I'm pretty close -- I'm just not sure how to broadcast an event using ImageMapEventArgs. Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your code to a separate method and call that method from the handler.

Calling event handlers directly is bad practice.

Comment: I just thought it might be better practice to raise the event as opposed to making my logic for drilling down a public method.

Comment: No; it's better to put that logic into a private method.  It should take the logical parameters it needs (`sessionKey`?), and you should extract those parameters in the click handler.

Comment: I would if I could :) Intermediary steps where I'm slowly but surely integrating ASP.NET AJAX code into MVC. Thanks though -- I will follow this advice and put a TODO to make it private when feasible.

Comment: You mean this is in another class? I see.